# wordpress - dynamic sidebar will not hold any widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, widget, sidebar

Here is the code in functions.php:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=> 'Home Page Advanced Search',
    'id' => 'custom'
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=> 'Profile Picture Upload',
    'id' => 'pic upload'
));
```

Then, I use the two sidebars in my template like this:

```
?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom' )) : ?>
            <div id="widget-area">              
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom' ); ?>
            </div>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'pic upload' )) : ?>
            <div id="upload-photo-area">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'pic upload' ); ?>
            </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The sidebar with id='custom' works fine. I am able to put widgets in it in my dashboard and display them. The sidebar with id='pic upload' is not working correctly. All widgets that I put inside of it do not stay there (in the dashboard API) and, therefore, do not display on my page.

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have a space in the name of a sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a space in the name of a sidebar. As per the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar#Multiple_Sidebars)

> If you name your own ID values in the register_sidebar() WordPress
>   function, you might increase readability of the code. The ID should be
>   all lowercase alphanumeric characters **and not contain white space**. You
>   can also use the - and _ characters. IDs must be unique and cannot
>   match a sidebar name. Using your own IDs can also make the sidebar
>   name translatable.

I added the emphases.
Change `pic upload` to `pic-upload` or `pic_upload` should fix that.